# spring jpa authentication fail

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm running postgres as docker container and using spring jpa trying to connect with the DB. simple operation. Even though, I gave right username and password, still JPA throws following exception

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "admin"

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

Comment: sorry, cannot reproduce! (when run this docker-compose, with a (quickstart) spring-boot-data-jpa, (both!) on localhost, i can query the db...) so according to your error message, you must have a modified image/some property sources interfering (env,profiles, ...) /...

Comment: @xerx593 is right. I ve tried your application.properties with this little sample projet https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=postgresql,data-jpa,web and it works perfectly.   Are you using only one properties file  ?

Comment: > org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "admin" usualy means the user password is  not correct or authentication method is not set correctly. In your case Docker configure the authentication method for you. And your password is correct. So the issu must come from somewhere else.

Comment: @soung yes I'm using only one property file and one docker-compose file to deploy postgresql. password cant be wrong. If you see in docker-compose yaml I have mentioned password and user name as admin. The same details are used in property file.

Comment: Wee need more detail to help you. If you can,  share your project or some code snippet with us

Comment: @soung how to share project snippet, you mean entire project?. I already shared property file and docker compose file

Comment: if your code is not confidential, you can create a public repository on a git provider  (like github, or gitlab ) and commit there your source code.